# Bootstrap datepicker not working in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap datepicker just won't work for me. I know this question has been asked before but after searching a long time I could not find an answer.

I have the following configurations. When loading the page, the input field appears but no calendar to select appears when clicking on the field. Any help is very appreciated.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require prototype
//= require prototype_ujs
//= require effects
//= require dragdrop
//= require controls
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_self

$('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker()
```

application.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 */
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

and in the view

```
<input type="text" data-behaviour='datepicker' >
```

I have tried a couple of variations suggested in other topics on stackoverflow, but none of them worked. E.g.,

```
$(function() {
$('#dp5').datepicker()
});
```

together with

```
<input class="span2" id="dp5" readonly="" value="02-02-2012" size="16">
```

does not work neither.

Comment: One thing I don't see in your application.js file is jQuery which bootstrap-datepicker needs to run.  Any chance that could be your problem?

Comment: No, i just forgot to paste this in the question.

Comment: Did you solved this already? If not, any js error message you can show us? (you could check the javascript console on Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this gem: https://github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails ?

It will pack your Javascript and CSS required for datetimepicker into rails asset pipeline properly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens because of the jquery version in your case

```
//= require jquery
```

Try downloading another version of the jquery and replace your current one. I had the exact same problem and that was the solution. Try with versions 1.5 or 2.0 or something like that.

Also, please note that by:

```
//= require_tree .
```

You are including .js files from the javascript directory, so please be sure that you haven't downloaded another version of jquery and you are automatically including second version also. You will have conflict issues.

If it all doesn't work you can try to look at the answer here also [jQuery in Rails 3.2 not displaying datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562009/jquery-in-rails-3-2-not-displaying-datepicker)

**Important:**

Make sure when you are testing to **refresh your page with** `ctrl+ F5` ! It will refresh the whole page from the beginning and it will not include cashed elements and this is very important as you might find a solution, but due cashing you will not notice the change and you could miss the solution only because of the cashing.