# jQuery in Rails 3.2 not displaying datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have searched for it, but I can't find anything that's exactly for my case. It seems that jQuery not working properly in Rails is a very common problem because it is included twice.

In my case, I am not very sure what is happening. I have a script.js file which is included in the application and contains:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#to_date").datepicker();
    $("#from_date").datepicker();

});
```

The datepicker() doesn't show up.

I have `jquery-rails` in my Gemfile and it is included in the html source.

If I change my `script.js` file to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#to_date").hide();

});
```

it works perfectly!

So the problem is not necessarily from jQuery being included twice, or at least that's what I think.

I'd hate to spend another 3 hours trying to solve it. Just throw out any idea that you have, no matter how foolish it may seem.

Comment: how are your creating #to_date, i.e. is it a date field or a text field?  The datepicker only works if you attach it to a text input field.

Comment: Try `console.log($.ui.version)`. jQuery works, we know that, but maybe jQuery UI is broken in the gem. That'd cause `datepicker()` to fail as it's part of jQuery UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Gemfile, add

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

and then in your `application.js`, add

```
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

Find more detailed info for the ui gem [on github](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails).

Answer (score 0):

Please, Check the order of jquery file, in which pattern it is loading.

`First of all jquery file has to be loaded then UI`, or remaining files.